# magento 2 override block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.0, debug

I am trying to override block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header
But it is not working at all no error.
Any suggestion?

Created new module.
Header.php code

```
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace Webkul\MagentoTheme\Block\Html;

/**
* Html page header block
*/
class Header extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header
{
public function HelloWorld()
{
    echo "Hello World Dear Hamza ......................................";
    die();
}
}
```

etc/di.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" type="Webkul\MagentoTheme\Block\Html\Header" />
</config>
```

Comment: how you know it is not working? did you call `HelloWorld` method anywhere?

Comment: Called   $block->HelloWorldx(); in header.phtml file

Comment: @Agnes But no output.

Comment: is your module enabled? you can check the output of bin/magento module:status. Also if you add echo get_class($block) to your template file what do you get?

Comment: @ Kristof at Fooman  yes my module is enabled and checked it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you upgrade and clean the cache?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If no - do it, please. I did not find mistakes in above code.

Comment: Hey @Evgeny Levinsky I already did that.But no luck yet.

Comment: Send me all files in your module: **etc/module.xml**, **registration.php** and **header.phtml**, if it possible. I will check it in my environment

Comment: all files https://ufile.io/a18ci

Comment: Ok, thanks. Show me how the header block is called in your xml layout, I have any ideas.

Comment: Called like   echo $block->HelloWorldx();

Comment: Try add `<referenceBlock name="header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml" />` in your **/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** (define template with module). Everything is working fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64814/discussion-between-danial-butt-and-evgeny-levinsky).